# JAVA: How do I properly store Objects in a Binary File? Without overwriting

Tags: java, file, oop, object, binary

I'm working on a Java File I/O Interface, I need my files to be in binary format, not in strings. I've found ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream useful for my needs, but I need the interface to be able to write at the end of my file, as of I need it to record future data in the same file over and over.

I tried using the FileOutputStream(String file, boolean append) constructor but since my class implements Serializable there seems to be an issue. When it attempts to read a second record it throws a **StreamCorruptedException**. I know it must be because there's this **header** that kind of describes the object's fields.

My question is, how can I store objects succesfully? I like using objects, because it makes it easier to structure and handle data. This is my code so far:

```
try
    {
        FileOutputStream outFile;
        ObjectOutputStream outStream;
        FileInputStream inFile;
        ObjectInputStream inStream;

        outFile = new FileOutputStream("people.mcf", true);
        outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);

        //Writing the objects
        System.out.println("Writing file...");
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            outStream.writeObject(people[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Finished writing file...");
        outFile.close();
        outStream.close();
        //Reading the files
        System.out.println("Attempting to read file...");
        inFile = new FileInputStream("people.mcf");
        inStream = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);
        Person buffer;
        while(true)
        {                
            buffer = (Person)inStream.readObject();
            System.out.println(buffer.getData());
        }

    }
    catch(EOFException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Reached end of file...");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
```

This is the Person class:

```
static class Person implements Serializable
{
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final String address;

    public Person(String name, int age, String address)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
    }               

    public String getData()
    {
        return name + " " + age + " " + address;
    }       
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
Writing file...
Finished writing file...
Attempting to read file...
Andres 26 Palo Gordo
Pilar 22 Palo Gordo
Kelvin 27 Palo Gordo
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

EDIT: I'm not asking why I'm getting the StreamCorruptedException, I'm aware that ObjectOutputStream is causing this, what I'm asking for is another way to store Object data in a structured manner.

Comment: `The objects must be read back from the corresponding ObjectInputstream with the same types and in the same order as they were written.`
And you are reading them in while true loop. Can you try reading only 3 objects? Maybe you are getting StreamCorrupted exception instead of EOFException.

Comment: You can't append objects to an Object Stream. It has a header and a footer. btw if you want to write an array to an object stream, just write the array as it's an object too.

Comment: @MikhailBoyarsky I know for a fact that there are more than 3 registers, because with a clean file it reads just fine.

Comment: @PeterLawrey is there a way to store data in an organized way so I can read it later and maybe store it in an object?

Comment: @AndresRincon yes, too many to mention here. The simplest solution is to do what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

**If your record is of FIXED LENGTH or at least of MAXIMUM length, the following code do the job.**

Using [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) you'll be able to seek the file pointer to write new, or update an already existing record. See [Indexed File in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_file).

To be more portable, you may serialize the record using [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), already used by [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) which is an interface to RandomAccessFile, see [RandomAccessFile.getChannel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#getChannel--).

Code sample:

Person class revisited:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Person implements ISerializable<UUID> {

   private final UUID   _id;
   private final String _name;
   private final int    _age;
   private final String _address;

   public Person( ByteBuffer source ) {
      _id      = SerializeUtil.unserializeUUID( source );
      _name    = SerializeUtil.unserializeString( source );
      _age     = source.get();
      _address = SerializeUtil.unserializeString( source );
   }

   public Person( String name, int age, String address) {
      _id      = UUID.randomUUID();
      _name    = name;
      _age     = age;
      _address = address;
   }

   @Override
   public UUID getKey() {
      return _id;
   }

   @Override
   public void serialize( ByteBuffer target ) {
      target.clear();
      SerializeUtil.serializeUUID  ( _id     , target );
      SerializeUtil.serializeString( _name   , target );
      target.put((byte)_age );
      SerializeUtil.serializeString( _address, target );
   }
}
```

IndexFile class:

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class IndexedFile<K extends Comparable<K>, R extends ISerializable<K>>
   implements
      Closeable
{
   private final Map<K, Long>            _index = new TreeMap<>();
   private final RandomAccessFile        _file;
   private final FileChannel             _channel;
   private final ByteBuffer              _record;
   private final Function<ByteBuffer, R> _factory;

   public IndexedFile( File tracksFile, int recordSize, Function<ByteBuffer, R> factory ) throws IOException {
      _file    = new RandomAccessFile( tracksFile, "rw" );
      _channel = _file.getChannel();
      _record  = ByteBuffer.allocate( recordSize );
      _factory = factory;
      _channel.truncate( 0 );
   }

   @Override
   public void close() throws IOException {
      _file.close();
      _channel.close();
   }

   public int size() {
      return _index.size();
   }

   public int recordSize() {
      return _record.capacity();
   }

   public void put( R record ) throws IOException {
      final K    key    = record.getKey();
      final Long offset = _index.get( key );
      if( offset != null ) {
         _channel.position( offset );
      }
      else {
         final long pos = _channel.size();
         _channel.position( pos );
         _index.put( key, pos );
      }
      record.serialize( _record );
      _record.position( _record.limit());
      _record.flip();
      _channel.write( _record );
   }

   public R read( int recNo ) throws IOException {
      if( recNo >= _index.size()) {
         return null;
      }
      final long offset = recNo*_record.capacity();
      _channel.position( offset );
      _record.clear();
      _channel.read( _record );
      _record.flip();
      return _factory.apply( _record );
   }

   public R get( K key ) throws IOException {
      final Long offset = _index.get( key );
      if( offset == null ) {
         return null;
      }
      _channel.position( offset );
      _record.clear();
      _channel.read( _record );
      _record.flip();
      return _factory.apply( _record );
   }
}
```

For completeness, utility class:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.UUID;

public final class SerializeUtil {

   public static void serializeString( String s, ByteBuffer target ) {
      final byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
      target.putInt( bytes.length );
      target.put( bytes );
   }

   public static String unserializeString( ByteBuffer target ) {
      final int length = target.getInt();
      final byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
      target.get( bytes );
      return new String( bytes );
   }

   public static void serializeUUID( UUID id, ByteBuffer target ) {
      target.putLong( id.getMostSignificantBits());
      target.putLong( id.getLeastSignificantBits());
   }

   public static UUID unserializeUUID( ByteBuffer source ) {
      final long msb = source.getLong();
      final long lsb = source.getLong();
      return new UUID( msb, lsb );
   }
}
```

And the interface ISerializable:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public interface ISerializable<K extends Comparable<K>> {

   public K getKey();

   public void serialize( ByteBuffer target );
}
```

Comment: You can to clarify how this answer relates to the question. I can imagine what you might mean, but there is too many dots to join.

Comment: Code added to join the dots...